# How do I fix DBContext Migration error Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''?

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to migrate a mysql database to my C# API, but I get the following error message in powershell:
*"BUILD STARTED....
BUILD SUCCEEDED
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728%22)*

I have been making a carbon copy of a previous database + API I made and it looks 100% the same from what I can see. I tried asking AI, I tried following the link and looking for a solution from Microsoft, but everything I can think of looks good. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You might want to try looking into Efcore scaffolding. It can auto create the code for you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli